# Plotting an ROC curve with spacy

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, roc

I have managed to train a custom NER model using Spacy and I would like to demonstrate its ROC curve. I am able to use Scorer (https://spacy.io/api/scorer) to get final Recall, Precision and F-score but I would like to visualise the ROC curve in matplotlib.

How would I go about plotting the ROC using this platform?

Answer (score 1):

A ROC curve is plotted based on variation when changing the classification threshold. But the spaCy NER model doesn't have a threshold parameter for classification, so you can't do this.

You could strain a spancat and use the threshold setting in that to get a curve.